# Locally implement subscription payment

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

I am developing a subscription based app. When the user makes a payment, the server sends to the app the payment receipt.

The app is designed to be used in offline mode, so unless the user is making subscription payment, they might not contact the server.

I want to design an offline payment method where the user can use the app for duration of the payment only. I want the payment duration to be reliable even though the user changes their phones time/date.

I've tried using AlarmManager to periodically update remaining payment counter. But this doesn't work when  the user sets the date to the past, I've tried to listen to DATE_CHANGE broadcast. But that also doesn't get broadcast when the date is set to the past.

I want to know what is the right way of implementing this type of functionality. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible but have you looked for a way to get the time from the cell network?

Comment: I will try that, one thing to note is some users of the app don't have their time to be set to be the cell network's time.